# Async Pluggable Protocol Handler: Forward to other protocol?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

When implementing an asyncrhonous plauggable protocol handler, is it possible to "redirect" the implementation to another protocol?

Instantiating the protocol handler for another protocol (such as file: or res:) looks a bit scary and not intended.

Comment: Long time ago, it was indeed possible for IE6. Chance are it's still possible.

Comment: @Noseratio: do you still remember how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `IInternetProtocolSink::ReportResult` passing `INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED` for the first parameter, and the desired URL for the last (the second parameter doesn't matter; 302 would be as good a choice as any).

Answer (score 1):

I used `IInternetProtocolSink::ReportProgress(BINDSTATUS_REDIRECTING, pszRedirURL)` from `IInternetProtocolRoot::Start`, and then simply redirected everything to `pszRedirURL` protocol's `IInternetProtocol`. As I mentioned in the comments, that worked for IE6. A lot of IE internals has changed since then.